# Include 'UTC` in datetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails

One of my assertions is failing because of this slight niggle:

```
  its(:register_token_created_at){ should eq DateTime.now.utc }
```

**results in:**

```
  expected: Fri, 28 Mar 2014 00:06:33 +0000
       got: Fri, 28 Mar 2014 00:06:33 UTC +00:00
```

So how should I change `DateTime.now.utc` for it to pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you have your **test environment** with the following configuration:

**yourapp/config/environments/test.rb**

```
#config.time_zone = "whatever"
config.active_record.default_timezone = :utc
```

Then, you can replace:

```
DateTime.now.utc #Fri, 28 Mar 2014 00:54:28 +0000
```

With:

```
Time.zone.now #Fri, 28 Mar 2014 00:54:51 UTC +00:00
```

That works for me...

Another (ugly) solution can be:

```
DateTime.now.utc.strftime("%a, %m %b %Y %H:%M:%S UTC %:z") #"Fri, 03 Mar 2014 00:55:46 UTC +00:00"
```

And then, you can compare as strings